# Replace the phone number by a contact name in iOS, Android SMS body

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, sms, gsm

We at our website send invitation messages via SMS. Users can specify the number of their friend, and this friend will receive the following SMS message on his/her phone:

```
+37300123456 invited you to join our service, blah blah...
```

Normally this +37300123456 (it's a Moldovan phone number, non-existing) exists in user's contact list. Our target customers use Android and iOS.

Is that possible to send something like control text (see example below)

```
{contact:+37300123456} invited you to join our service, blah blah...
```

Which will display on the user's phone like

```
Homer Simpson invited you to join our service, blah blah...
```

Comment: No. SMS is just plain text, and how a message is displayed is entirely up to the client app. Most Android apps will show phone numbers, URLs, etc., as links if they are detected in the message body, but there's nothing you can include in a text to "force" them to do so.

Comment: @MikeM. You may want to post your comment as an answer and I'll mark the question answered. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that possible to send something like control text[?]

Unfortunately, no. An SMS message is just plain text, and how a message is displayed is entirely up to the client app. Most Android SMS apps will show phone numbers, URLs, etc., as links to open the appropriate app if they are detected in the message body, but there's nothing you can include in a text message to "force" them to do so.